# Prevent Replay once errored?

Tags: system.reactive

I have a stream that simply emits an established network connection, and when that connection goes down for whatever reason, emits an error.  An established connection allows me to obtain any number of streams of data from the server.

Since I want to re-use the connection, and I want it to reconnect on errors, I do the following.

```
var sharedConnection = connection
.Retry()
.Replay(1)
.RefCount()
```

It works really well, re-connecting whenever there's a network error.  When all the streams have run down, the connection is disposed. This is great, and what I'd expect. However, the first subsequent stream request is replayed the initial disposed connection, instead of a new one. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, you're not doing anything wrong. That's what `.RefCount` does. Can you provide a [mcve] for us to work with to try find an alternative?

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for your reply.  I'll reduce it and create a gist

Comment: Please, if you create a gist, can you also include the code directly in your question? There shouldn't be external links unless those links support content already in your question.